# Bay Trail Z3740 and Ubuntu issues, any help?

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04

I am having trouble to run Ubuntu on my `LG SlidePad 2 with Z3740 processor`.

The problem is that I can't find a way to boot the pendrive on it. I can get into the `BIOS/UEFI` but there is no way I can boot the pen drive. I tried to follow the same procedures of `Asus T100` but it isn't the same, so it didn't work.

Is there any way I can boot up from the pendrive?

Answer (score 0):

I got to boot my 11T540 through a pendrive following this procedure 'https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md
Now I can not make the wifi device work properly.
If you get to use the wireless device, please answer my question regarding 11T540.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use Rufus http://rufus.akeo.ie/ to create bootable drives to install any OS on PCs with UEFI. Disable "secure boot" in BIOS.